# How to join these queries?

Tags: mysql, subquery, pivot

So I currently have this query:

```
SELECT v.Voorstellingsnummer, COUNT(r.Voorstellingsnummer) 
FROM reserveringen r, voorstelling v 
WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer 
GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) < 50
```

That query outputs this table:

```
Voorstellingsnummer  COUNT(r.Voorstellingsnummber)
-------------------  -----------------------------
4                    1
5                    2
```

The other query is this one:

```
SELECT v.Tijd, v.Voorstellingsnummer
FROM voorstelling v
WHERE v.Vestigingsnaam = 'Amsterdam' 
AND v.Filmnaam = 'Avengers'
```

...which outputs this:

```
Tijd                 Voorstellingsnummer
-------------------  -------------------
2019-03-24 11:12:00  5
2019-03-24 15:12:00  4
```

**Considerations**

- I need to add a `COUNT(v.Voorstellingsnummer)` column to the last image the same way as it is in the first one.
- And then I need to add those COUNTS together to give a `totalcount`.
- That total count should be lower than a set number and if it's higher it should not be shown.

When I do this:

```
SELECT v.Tijd, v.Voorstellingsnummer, COUNT(v.Voorstellingsnummer)
FROM voorstelling v
WHERE v.Vestigingsnaam = 'Amsterdam' 
AND v.Filmnaam = 'Avengers'
```

...it returns this:

```
Tijd,                Voorstellingsnummer, COUNT(v.Voorstellingsnummer)
2019-03-24 11:12:00, 5,                   2
```

...but instead it should show both the times form the second picture both with a count of 1.

Those counts of 1 should be combined with the other table so the final counts of 
`Voorstellingsnummer=4` should be 2
and `Voorstellingsnummer=5` should be 3

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

**Further information**

Basically if the table `reserveringen` look has `(Voorstellingsnummer = 4)` 6x 
and the table `voorstelling` has `(Voorstellingsnummer = 4)` 2x
the count outputted by the query should be 8x.

However, currently if `(Voorstellingsnummer = 4)` appears 3x in the table `voorstelling`, but has 0 appearances in the table `reserveringen` it won't be counted.

So what I'm thinking is running this query:

```
SELECT v.Voorstellingsnummer, COUNT(r.Voorstellingsnummer) 
FROM reserveringen r, voorstelling v 
WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer 
GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) < 50
```

for the table `reserveringen` and the table `voorstelling`. That should result in two tables. The result of the query for table `voorstelling` should look like this (using number previously mentioned):

```
Tijd         Voorstellingsnummer   COUN
----------   -------------------   ----
something    5                      1
something    4                      1
```

..and then the result for the query for table `reserveringen` should look as follows:

```
Voorstellingsnummer   COUNT
-------------------   -----
5                      2
```

That's because table `reserveringen` has no `Tijd` column.

Those two tables should then be combined into the following one:

```
Tijd         Voorstellingsnummer    COUNT
---------    -------------------    -----
something    5                      3
something    4                      1
```

Basically both `Voorstellingsnummer` 4/5 approve of the condition `Vestigingsnaam='Amsterdam' AND Filmnaam='Avengers'`; however only `Voorstellingsnummer` 5 appears in the `reserveringen` table. Because of that I need to know how much appearances `Voorstellingsnummer = (Some number)` has over both tables.

**Note**: *Reserveringen* means *reservations* in dutch, and *voorstelling* is *show*. 
Some shows might have reservations but some might not. Because the show without reservations should still be listed (as it's not full yet).

Comment: Please post the results as text and not as pictures. There are users who are on networks that block imgur and are unable to load the pictures and unable to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post them as text would just copying the results work? Otherwise it would take me at least one hour to do that by hand

Comment: You don't have the ability to export as csv or some other format from your sql tool? The main thing is to have them in a format that isn't just a picture so that more people can see it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using my schoolserver (I'm a graduate high school student) and we are using phpmyadmin so I think there should be a way to export as CSV but I don't know where

Comment: First you `JOIN`, then you "pivot".

Answer (score 0):

In advance i've never written anything in mysql, but the theory should still be there in case of small syntax errors.

In general i'd advice using INNER JOINS, instead of joining your tables in a WHERE clause, due to easier readability and better coding practice, as it makes it easy to change the sql inner join to an outer join as i've shown below:

```
SELECT v.Voorstellingsnummer, COUNT(r.Voorstellingsnummer)+1 
FROM voorstelling v
INNER JOIN reserveringen r ON r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer
WHERE v.Vestigingsnaam = 'Amsterdam' 
AND v.Filmnaam = 'Avengers' 
GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) < 50
```

I am however very confused as to how you want the counts added? The above query should return what you're asking for. As it sounds like you just want the initial counts to be added with 1. To have this match more function like instead of a hardcoded value, i would have to understand why 4 and 5 should have a count of 1 in the other table?

Comment: Your code indeed is more clean and does what I want partly. problem is that If I where to remove Voorstellingsnummer = 4 from the reserveringen table it will no longer return that Voorstellingsnummer = 4 as it will no longer be counted. So it's not a simple + 1 but it should add the amount it's counted in the table voorstelling to the amount it's counted in the table reserveringen. I edited my question to give a better explaination

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. I got it working after I edited and everything became clear. This is the query that helped me obtain the desired information:

```
SELECT Tijd
FROM voorstelling v
WHERE v.Voorstellingsnummer NOT IN
(
SELECT r.Voorstellingsnummer
FROM reserveringen r
WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer
GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50
)
AND Vestigingsnaam = 'Amsterdam'
AND Filmnaam = 'Avengers';
```